# LR Analysis API cross session

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Is it possible to create a cross session via the LoadRunner Analysis API?

i.e feeding 2 .lrr files to the the session.create function, then generating a cross session summary report (I know graph comparison is unavailable as of 12.55)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "Working with multiple sessions" topic in the documentation, which is downloadable here - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56/help/analysis_API/AnalysisAPI.chm

Comment: Thanks, I mean specifically creating a cross session report